# OnClick cant find the sub i'm calling

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm building some html text to put on a window.
It works mostly as intended but a button I'm displaying - when clicked cant find the subroutine I'm calling. I just cant see what I've missed or doing wrong. Not sure if I need javascript? Thanks.

'OpenImage' is a subroutine on the server side. I pass this some variables.
'details' is the text string I'm creating.

```
details = details & "<input type=""image"" runat=""server"" ID=""ButtonOpen"" src=""../Images/icon_view.gif"" OnClick=""openimage('" & recDataSP.ItemUkey.ToString() & "','" & quote & "','')"" />"
```

Comment: can you put some code? people can't guess how you coded it :)

Comment: sorry forgot to indent!

Comment: That code doesn't make much sense to me.  Could you elaborate?  What are you building?  What is the end result supposed to do?  And post some code around that line.  Just post everything that is relevant, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly shouldn't you be declaring your button with the javascript and then declare your image.

```
<button id="BtnSave" runat="server" OnClick=""openimage('" & recDataSP.ItemUkey.ToString() & "','" & quote & "','')"" />"><img src="Images/save.png" />Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into my page and i came to know that there is a problem with quotes

```
details = details & "<input type=\"image\" runat=\"server\" ID=\"ButtonOpen\"src=\"../Images/icon_view.gif\"OnClick=\"openimage('recDataSP.ItemUkey.ToString()','quote','');\"/>"
```

replace your code with the given code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. Fell into place when I saw the comments. Combination of wrong quotes and order.